# Update Mozilla Firefox version using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

My website is not working over Mozilla Firefox older version.Can it possible to update Mozilla Firefox using jquery not do manually update.

Comment: no it is not possible unless they provide any API..(I think no ;))

Comment: I don't think so. At least, I hope not! However, it's easy to check the version in the useragent string, alert the user they are using an older version and refuse to show anything until they have updated.

Comment: Sorry, a web application should never be able to force software installation on a client machine.

Comment: By the way, why is this question tagged C# and ASP.NET? Firefox is written in C++ and your question is about Javascript. Unless you want to do the processing server-side. That could be done too, but it still won't allow you to force an update of the software on the client machine.

Answer (score 3):

Impossible! You cannot force users to update a program on their machine.
Just imagine this, you are visiting a site and they could simple instal a random program (adware or other malicious programs) without manual input just by javascript, thats just pure horror.

The only thing you can do is getting the version of the firefox and kindly ask the user to update to the lastest version of firefox, just as a information.

Here is a good website that explains how to implement such feature:
http://browser-update.org/en/

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. You options:

- fix you site to work in older versions of Firefox
- warn user about older version on point to the latest version install location
- suggest other browser
- do nothing (i.e. you don't care about that type of users)